# Why does this python implementation of an "operable function" fail?

Tags: python, decorator

I wanted to demonstrate the usefulness of decorators in python to some people and failed at a simple example: Consider two functions (for sake of simplicity without arguments) `f` and `g`.
One can define their sum f+g as the function that returns f() + g(). Of course adding, subtracting etc. of functions is not defined in general. But it is easy to write a decorator that transforms every function into an addable function.

Now I would like to have a decorator that transforms any function into an "operable" function, that is, a function that behaves in the described way for any operator in the standard module `operator`. My implementation looks as follows:

```
import operator

class function(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self):
        return self.f()

def op_to_function_op(op):
    def function_op(self, operand):
        def f():
            return op(self(), operand())
        return function(f)
    return function_op
binary_op_names = ['__add__', '__and__', '__div__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__ge__', '__gt__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__or__', '__pow__', '__sub__', '__truediv__', '__xor__']
for name in binary_op_names:
    type.__setattr__(function, name, op_to_function_op(getattr(operator, name)))
```

Let's perform a little test to see if it works:

```
@function
def a():
    return 4

def b():
    return 7

c = a + b
print c()
print c() == operator.__add__(4, 7)
```

Output:

```
11
True
```

This is the final version I got after some experimenting.
Now let's do two small, irrelevant modifications to have a look what I tried before:

*First*: In the definition of `binary_op_names`, change the square brackets to round brackets. Suddenly, a (for me) completely unrelated error message comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 30, in <module>
    c = a + b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'
```

Where does this come from??

*Second*: Write `op_to_function_op` as a lambda expression:

```
op = getattr(operator, name)
type.__setattr__(function, name, lambda self, other: function(lambda: op(self(), other())))
```

Perform a slightly more involved test case:

```
@function
def a():
    return 4

def b():
    return 7

c = a + b
print c()
print c() == operator.__add__(4, 7)
print c() == operator.__xor__(4, 7)
```

Output:

```
3
False
True
```

This looks to me like scope leakage, but again I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: type.__setattr__ seems to do something evil .. don't know what. The list to tuple thing is really strange. If you change type.__setattr__ to setattr everything seems to work.

Comment: The typical `memoize` decorator applied to the fibonacci sequence and other cache-friendly problems might be a better application to demonstrate decorators.

Comment: The tuple issue seems to be a heinous bug.  I'm seeing the same behavior.  Absolutely everything about `name` checks out, but `type.__setattr__` fails to work.

Comment: Yes, the strange question actually is why type.__setattr__ actually works. I can't remember why I used it.

Comment: @Daenyth, thank for an unhelpful comment ;) I actually did demonstrate `memoize` right before I tried to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, I didn't see any problems when changing `binary_op_names` from a `list` to a `tuple`, not sure why you were seeing that.

As for the second issue, all operations will perform an XOR because `__xor__` was the last item that `op` was set to.  Because `op` is not passed into the lambda when it is created, each time the lambda is called it will look for `op` in a global scope and always see `__xor__`.

You can prevent this by creating a lambda that acts as a closure, similar to your current `op_tofunction_op`, it might end up looking something like this:

```
op_to_function_op = lambda f: lambda self, other: function(lambda: f(self(), other()))
for name in binary_op_names:
    op = getattr(operator, name)
    type.__setattr__(function, name, op_to_function_op(op))

>>> (function(lambda: 4) + (lambda: 7))()
11
>>> (function(lambda: 4) - (lambda: 7))()
-3
>>> (function(lambda: 4) ^ (lambda: 7))()
3
```

Comment: Did you use type.__setattr__ or setattr? (See discussion in the main comment thread)
Thanks for the clarification on the lambdas!

Comment: I used `type.__setattr__` and it seemed to work, but I don't use `setattr` or `type.__setattr__` much so I can't really comment much on which is preferable.